How do I make screen space shaders
When I play video games or watch highly stylized animations I see shader effects that seem not possible to make in blender. These shaders allow you to mess to directly draw pixels onto the screen space or take pixels that are already present on the screen space from the scene behind the object.
Effects that can be achieved:
Flat textures that don't morph around mesh geometry.
Color filters, shaders.
Examples:
End Portal From minecraft

Hand drawn scibble shading effect
Shader effects that change the colors on the screen like color filters.

The question needs more focus: choose a single effect you want to reproduce in Blender. It's probably possible, but maybe not using a usual pipeline, because video game engines have different pipelines than Blender.

Hello, please add some screenshots of the effect you want to achieve, as it stands it's very hard to understand exactly what you want.

I realized that a camera data node helps achieve the effect where the camera view vector can be used in place for the uv vector inputs in texture related shading. So this answers one half of my questions. But still would like to find a way to edit graphics from parts of the scene that are behind the mesh.
